# Spliting an array into train and test sets with python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, random

I tried a method to split data between train and test sets, but it seems that it fill the train with zeros and leave the data in test...

#### In theory, it works :

When I apply the following function which randomly selects some columns of the given array, it worked with the DataLens with numpy matrix but not with others.

```
def train_test_split(array):
    test = np.zeros(array.shape)
    train = array.copy()
    for user in xrange(array.shape[0]):
        test_ratings = np.random.choice(array[user, :].nonzero()[0], 
                                        size=10, 
                                        replace=False)
        train[user, test_ratings] = 0.
        test[user, test_ratings] = ratings[user, test_ratings]

    # Test and training are truly disjoint
    assert(np.all((train * test) == 0)) 
    return train, test

train, test = train_test_split(ratings)
```

#### With simple data it doesn't work :

When using simple data :

```
ratings :
[[ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  1.]]
```

It fill the array with 0 one by one even if train was a copy of ratings at the very beginning :

```
train :  
 [[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: Why do you use `train[user, test_ratings] = 0.`? Furthermore I don't get the disjoin test?

Comment: There is an easy method in sklearn, called [`train_test_split`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) to do this.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It's to remove from the train set what would be used in the other set. We can't train on what we will test, I believe it would be nonsense

Comment: @JNevens I think this is the right answer ! Thank you ! Still I don't understand why mine didn't worked :/